# Devexpress report name from textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am using dropdown list to specify the Devexpress report using if else statements as following

```
    if (Renm.Text == "cheminv")
    {               
        Reports.cheminv report = new Reports.cheminv();
        report.Parameters["WAus"].Value = Session["Username"].ToString();
        WeVI1.OpenReport(report);
    }
    else if (Renm.Text == "CRMInv")
    {
        Reports.CRMInv report = new Reports.CRMInv();
        WeVI1.OpenReport(report);
    }
```

Is there a way to pass the textbox value directly to be like

```
    Reports.Renm.Text report = new Reports.Renm.Text();
    report.Parameters["WAus"].Value = Session["Username"].ToString();
    WeVI1.OpenReport(report);
```

Comment: check if Reports.item("text name here", or Reports("text name here") exists as a collection or property of the report object (don't know the devExpress report object model. If not, then the suggestion/answer below to create a custom collection of reports in your own collection,  and then reference that custom collection by text name could also work. So, create your own custom class - pass it the name as string, and return the correct report object. This means for each new report, you probably have to update that class or collection, but it would at least allow use of string to choose report.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options.

Put the reports in a dictionary, something along the line of:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<Report>> reports = new()
{
  { "cheminv", () => new Reports.cheminv() },
  { "CRMInv", () => new Reports.CRMInv() }
}
var report = reports["cheminv"]();
WeVI1.OpenReport(report);
```

Use reflections

```
var report = (Report)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("CRMInv"));
WeVI1.OpenReport(report);
```

Comment: thanks @Nisd for your help, the idea there is to update the dropdown list and add a report without changing the code behind since the report name will be the same as the selected value, i think i will stay with else if in case i have to update the code anyway

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanSayed you should be able to do that via reflections.

Comment: thnx, am still trying figure out how to use reflection with this code but i think its the right way as i understand 